# Tab контрол с эффектом collapse работает не правильно

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужно сделать `tab-control` , чтобы вкладки открывались с эффектом `slideDown`.
 В начале все формы скрыты , нажимаем кнопку "Форма 1", открывается блок с эффектом `slideDown`, при нажатии кнопки "Форма 2" открывается другая форма, закрывая предыдущую.  Если нажимать на одну и ту же кнопку два раза, то просто открыть - закрыть форму (типа toggleClass).
 Вопрос такой,- когда я открываю первую форму, то при открытии второй она открывается снизу (а хотелось бы что бы она открывалась сверху). получается если открыть сначала вторую форму , а затем первую, то она открывается сверху, но если иначе, то вторая форма открывается снизу

*Получается если открывать сначала первую потом вторую (и последующую), то они снизу открываются, если же в обратном направлении, то сверху*

css

```
.tab-collapse-first, .tab-collapse-second,.tab-collapse-three{
    display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-12 p-0">
    <div class="button-wrapper-main">
        <a class="first-btn-tab btn-tab" data-target="first">Форма 1</a>
        <a class="second-btn-tab btn-tab" data-target="second">Форма 2</a>
        <a class="three-btn-tab btn-tab" data-target="three">Форма 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-12 p-0">
    <div class="tab-collapse-first tab-collapse">
        <p>ПЕРВАЯ ФОРМА ПЕРВАЯ ФОРМА ПЕРВАЯ ФОРМА ПЕРВАЯ ФОРМА ПЕРВАЯ ФОРМА ПЕРВАЯ ФОРМА ПЕРВАЯ ФОРМА ПЕРВАЯ ФОРМА ПЕРВАЯ ФОРМА ПЕРВАЯ ФОРМА ПЕРВАЯ ФОРМА ПЕРВАЯ ФОРМА ПЕРВАЯ ФОРМА</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-collapse-second tab-collapse">
        <p>ВТОРАЯ ФОРМА  ВТОРАЯ ФОРМА  ВТОРАЯ ФОРМА  ВТОРАЯ ФОРМА  ВТОРАЯ ФОРМА  ВТОРАЯ ФОРМА  ВТОРАЯ ФОРМА  ВТОРАЯ ФОРМА  ВТОРАЯ ФОРМА  ВТОРАЯ ФОРМА  ВТОРАЯ ФОРМА  ВТОРАЯ ФОРМА</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-collapse-three tab-collapse">
        <p>Третья форма Третья форма Третья форма Третья форма Третья форма Третья форма Третья форма Третья форма Третья форма Третья форма Третья форма Третья форма Третья форма </p>
    </div> 
</div>
```

js

```
$('.btn-tab').on('click',function(){
    target = $(this).attr('data-target');
    current_selector = '.tab-collapse-'+target;
    if ($(current_selector).hasClass('show-collapse')){
        $(current_selector).removeClass('show-collapse');
        $(current_selector).slideUp('fast');
    }
    else{
        hide_collapse();
        $(current_selector).addClass('show-collapse');
        $(current_selector).slideDown('fast');
    }
})

function hide_collapse(){
    $('.tab-collapse').each(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('show-collapse')){
            $(this).removeClass('show-collapse');
            $(this).slideUp('fast');
        }
    });
}
```

Функцию написал , так как количество вкладок в будущем будет расти , что бы было легче отслеживать открытые вкладки

Comment: Сначала хотел использовать bootstrap collapse , но там так же работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой вариант устроит?)

```js
$('.tab-item').on('click', function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
    var tabIndex = $(this).index();
    $('.tab-item.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    //
    $('.tabs-content').slideUp('slow', function() {
      $('.tab-content.active').removeClass('active');
      $('.tab-content').eq(tabIndex).addClass('active');
    }).slideDown('slow');

    console.clear();
    console.info(tabIndex);
  }
});
```

```css
.tabs {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.tabs::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.tab-item {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-item.active {
  background: #aaa;
}

.tabs-content {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 24px);
  padding: 10px 12px;
  background: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tab-content:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab-item active">tab 1</div>
  <div class="tab-item">tab 2</div>
  <div class="tab-item">tab 3</div>
  <div class="tab-item">tab 4</div>
  <div class="tab-item">tab 5</div>
</div>
<div class="tabs-content">
  <div class="tab-content active">tab content 1</div>
  <div class="tab-content">tab content 2</div>
  <div class="tab-content">tab content 3</div>
  <div class="tab-content">tab content 4</div>
  <div class="tab-content">tab content 5</div>
</div>
```